# JQ query output in csv format

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have been trying to extract a csv from the below json file using jq but not able to get so far. Does any experts out here can help?

```js
{
  "values": [
    {
      "resourceId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx-8b16-xxxxxx",
      "property-contents": {
        "property-content": [
          { 
            "statKey": "config|name",
            "timestamps": [
              1517591034069
            ],
            "values": [
              "somebname.UNIVERSE.test.com"
            ]
          },
          { 
            "statKey": "summary|guest|ipAddress",
            "timestamps": [
              1517591034069
            ],
            "values": [
              "100.xx.5.xx"
            ]
          },
          { 
            "statKey": "summary|parentCluster",
            "timestamps": [
              1551120506024
            ],
            "values": [
              "UFO-UFO"
            ]
          },
          { 
            "statKey": "summary|parentDatacenter",
            "timestamps": [
              1551120806021
            ],
            "values": [
              "GALAXY-D123"
            ]
          },
                    { 
            "statKey": "summary|parentVcenter",
            "timestamps": [
              1517591334271
            ],
            "values": [
              "X-RAY123"
            ]
          },
          { 
            "statKey": "summary|runtime|powerState",
            "timestamps": [
              1517591034069
            ],
            "values": [
              "Powered On"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    ..
    ...
```

```
xxx-xxxx-xxx-8b16-xxxxxx,somebname.UNIVERSE.test.com,100.xx.5.xx,UFO-UFO,GALAXY-D123,X-RAY123,Powered On
```

Expected o/p is:

```
xxx-xxxx-xxx-8b16-xxxxxx,somebname.UNIVERSE.test.com,100.xx.5.xx,UFO-UFO,GALAXY-D123,X-RAY123,Powered On
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output leaves some things unclear:

The second CSV column contains `somebname.UNIVERSE.test.com`, which was presumably derived from the section `"property-content": [ { ..., "values": [ "somebname.UNIVERSE.test.com" ], ... }`. How do you determine which element in the `"property-content"` list to pick for the second column? Is it because it's the first element? Is it because of its `"statKey": "config|name"`?

What if the `"property-content"` list is empty? What if it doesn't have the `"statKey"` entry you're looking for? What if the `"values"` list has zero or more than one element? The CSV row can only contain one scalar value. The same question applies for subsequent columns.

Making a wild guess here,

```
$ jq -r '.values[] | [ .resourceId, (."property-contents"."property-content"[] | .values[]) ] | join(",")' your.json
xxxx-xxxx-xxx-8b16-xxxxxx,somebname.UNIVERSE.test.com,100.xx.5.xx,UFO-UFO,GALAXY-D123,X-RAY123,Powered On
```

I cannot guarantee (and somewhat doubt) that this works in the general case, but I've been unable to extract a general case from your one example.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Your query gave me exactly what I need. I they do not have anything, nothing should be printed. Basically I was trying to get resourceId,config|name,summary|guest|ipAddress,summary|parentCluster,summary|parentDatacenter,summary|parentVcenter,summary|runtime|powerState

Comment: I spoke too soon. Basically, I wanted to get the values of the above keys in the order. However, in some cases, the key and the value pair may not be present in the input json, in which case I wanted to just return a null string. Is that possible?